# How to sample rows in the randomForest package

Tags: r, time-complexity, random-forest

I have a dataset with 1 million rows and 100 columns. `randomForest` is quite slow for data this big so I would like to train each tree on a subset of, say, 50000 columns each.

How do I achieve this with the `randomForest` function? Do I have to hack something together manually? I am not able to find any instruction on this in the vignette.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the sample for each tree should be different?

To start with, I would consider sampling before calling randomforest. Indeed, the fact that you take different samples for each tree could have an impact on the final result, and the importance matrix would probably be partly biased.

You can achieve this by doing that:

```
numrow <- nrow(data)
subset <- sample(numrow, 50000)
learn  <- data[subset,]
test   <- data[-subset,]
model_rf  <- randomForest(formula=[...], data=learn, importance=T)
```